# blackberry simulator 8300 Settings for internet access

Tags: blackberry-simulator

I want to access internet on my blackberry simulator 8300.
Can any one please help me to know how to do the setting on blackberry simulator 8300 for internet

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, perhaps, it can still help someone. ;)
You need to install the "BlackBerry Email and MDS Services Simulator Package" available on: https://www.blackberry.com/Downloads/entry.do?code=060AD92489947D410D897474079C1477
and run it before starting the BlackBerry simulator.
You need to do this same in all versions of the simulator to get internet access. ;)